# java SQL connection refused exception

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am newbie to java db coding...

This is my java code

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP",USER,PASS);
System.out.println("Creating statement...");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql;
```

This is the exception I am getting :

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/tiles].[default]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I am mySQL server also running and contains simple table named EMP. I am not interpreting the get connection URL comppletely. Can anyone explain it briefly?

Thanks.

Comment: "connection refused" = db's not running, tcp port is firewalled, socket is in the wrong place, blah blah blah.

Comment: Look at the server logfile to find out what is happend.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an SQL Express server using a MySQL driver?

Comment: is it a MySQL server or a MS SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong driver for the database. Every database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc.) has a different driver which is what connects between JDBC and the particular database's communication protocol.

You need the Microsoft SQL Server driver. You can download and install it from here if you don't already have it: [Microsoft down page for JDBC 4.0 driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774).

And here are the [instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) on how to add the jar to your classpath, and what URL to use. Note that in JDBC 4.0 and above, the `forName` is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 1):

from what i can see and understand is that you're missing the port.

you'd have done it in this way:

conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMP",USER,PASS);

The url can be describe in this way

jdbc: which is your connector
mysql:which is your current installed database
//hostname: which the machine hosting the server
portNumber: the port which allows the connection for the server
/databaseName: which is your created database.

hope it was helpful

Comment: and as further explained by @RealSkeptic, try to verify your path and that your database has been correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Microsoft JDBC driver and use `Class.forName(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver);`

If the problem still persists enable TCP/IP network protocol, which is disabled by default, and set the TCP/IP port to 1433 which is the default port number.